# Rigify rig won't "connect" to metarig

Tags: rigify

I have used the basic human metarig and made the bone structure within my mesh.

When I click *Generate Rig* I am given a new rig structure that is unassociated with my metarig.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Rigify rigs always generate as a separate object to the metarig. The reason your rig is so small is becuase you have to apply the scale for the metarig. To fix this press control a and then all transforms.

Comment: Yes, this was the answer.  I had to follow the instructions here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIK36p9UAGg

Comment: @dunnowhattocallmyself please consider writing a full answer rather than leaving this in the comments.